# Javascript property cannot reference property of the same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, javascript-objects

I am declaring this object:

```
var layout = {
    menu: {
        type: 0,
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        w: 50,
        h: 50
    },

    name: {
        type: 2,
        str: "name",
        x: 50+layout.menu.x,
        y: 40+layout.menu.y,
        h: 25
    }
}
```

But for some reason, when trying to reference "layout.menu", the console screams that it is undefined, when it is clearly defined just before it. Could anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

Comment: Related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `layout` only receives its value when the right part of the assignment has been evaluated first. Only *after* that evaluation the assignment to `layout` takes place. The *whole* object literal (until the end of the code you quoted) needs to be evaluated. Before the assignment takes place, even during the valuation of the object literal, the variable `layout` will still be undefined. Hence any reference to it in the object literal will be undefined.

To solve this, use an incremental approach:

```
var layout = {
    menu: {
        type: 0,
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        w: 50,
        h: 50
    }
};
// At this moment layout has a value with the "menu" property. So we continue:
layout.name = {
    type: 2,
    str: "name",
    x: 50+layout.menu.x,
    y: 40+layout.menu.y,
    h: 25
};
```

If you were intending to have a *live* reference to the values of `menu.x` and `menu.y`, so that any update of those property would immediately reflect inside the `name` structure, then you need a function, which could be a getter:

```
var layout = {
    menu: {
        type: 0,
        x: 50,
        y: 50,
        w: 50,
        h: 50
    },
    name: {
        type: 2,
        str: "name",
        get x() { return 50+layout.menu.x },
        get y() { return 40+layout.menu.y },
        h: 25
    }
};

// Demo
console.log(layout.name.x);
```

But this is not advisable as a solution if you *only* wanted to solve your initial reference problem, because with this solution *every* time you read the value of `layout.name.x`, the getter function is executed, which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Is there any way around this, so I don't have to declare each property separately like you suggest?

Comment: Can you explain why this does not work for you? It is just not possible to use a variable value which you have not assigned yet to that variable.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it just seems like a really strange way to declare an object. Would using `layout.onload = function() { ... declare the properties here ... }` work?

Comment: See addition to my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are calling menu before the object created with literal is actually assigned to the variable layout.

You can add menu and name properties one by one.

```
var layout = {};
 layout.menu = ...
 layout.name = ...
```